# Onhover image not centering

Tags: css, hover, center

Using pingendo and trying to do an image background with an on hover option. So the main image should be centered in the middle of the page and when you hover over it a second image appears. That part works, but its over to the left and if you look at it on a phone its way right. I've tried everything and I cannot get the page to center correctly. This is how I originally had it and it worked fine

```
<div class="cover">
   <div class="cover-image" style="background-image: url(images/bulb.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

but then I wanted to add the on hover so I added this to the head

```
<style type="text/css">
  .imgBox

        {
            width: 760px;
            height: 690px;
            background: url(/images/bulb.jpg) no-repeat;
        }
        .imgBox:hover {
            width: 760px;
            height: 690px;
            background: url(/images/bulb1.jpg) no-repeat;
            }
</style>


<div class="imgBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this in full page.

```css
.cover-image{
  width: 760px;
  height: 690px;
  background: url(https://dummyimage.com/760x690/000/fff) no-repeat;
  background-position:center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size:cover;
}
.cover-image:hover {
  width: 760px;
  height: 690px;
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/800x800/aba4ab/0011ff);
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
.cover-image{
  width: 100%;      
}
.cover-image:hover {
  width: 100%;     
}
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">
  <div class="cover-image"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: so this mostly worked, however on a cell phone the image still isn't centered, only on larger screens so i guess i have a resizing issue? Can you help? www.matthewpiton.com won't let me enter the code.

Comment: @Dorothy, now pls check I have updated code. and if you want to decrease background-image height then you can as you want.

Comment: AH!! that's perfect, thank you so much :-) Just as an aside, there is no way to have the hover work on a cell phone I guess?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
background: url(/images/bulb1.jpg) center no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **background-position: center;**

```css
.imgBox

        {
            width: 760px;
            height: 690px;
            background: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/425932d3f47c235613b3f2057f557414?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1) no-repeat;
            background-position: center; 
        }
        .imgBox:hover {
            width: 760px;
            height: 690px;
            background: url(https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/387d05f57adc80d01785be7dc7a506c5?s=328&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1) no-repeat;
            background-position: center;
            }
```

```html
<div class="imgBox"></div>
```